# Extracting IP addresses from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, extract, ipv4

I'm trying to extract IP addresses from an `asp` file in Python, the file looks something like this:

```
onInternalNet = (
        isInNet(hostDNS, "147.163.1.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
        isInNet(hostDNS, "123.264.0.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
        isInNet(hostDNS, "137.5.0.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
        isInNet(hostDNS, "100.01.02.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
        isInNet(hostDNS, "172.146.30.0", "255.240.0.0") ||
        isInNet(hostDNS, "112.268.0.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
```

How I'm attempting to extract them is with a regex:

```
if re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", line):
```

However I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pull_proxy.py", line 27, in <module>
    write_to_file(extract_proxies(in_file), out_file)
  File "pull_proxy.py", line 8, in extract_proxies
    if re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", line):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 233, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I don't understand why I'm getting that error, what can I do to this code to make it extract the information like I want it to?

```
import re

def extract_proxies(in_file):
    buffer = []

    for line in in_file:
        if re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", line):
            print "{} appened to buffer.".format(line)
            buffer.append(line)
        else:
            pass

    return buffer

def write_to_file(buffer, out_file):
    for proxy in buffer:
        with open(out_file, "a+") as res:
            res.write(proxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Running...."
    in_file = "C:/Users/thomas_j_perkins/Downloads/test.asp"
    out_file = "c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/Downloads/results.txt"
    write_to_file(extract_proxies(in_file), out_file)
```

**EDIT**

Realized I hadn't opened the file:

```
import re

def extract_proxies(in_file):
    buffer = []

    for line in in_file:
        if re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", line):
            print "{} appened to buffer.".format(line)
            buffer.append(line)
        else:
            pass

    in_file.close()
    return buffer

def write_to_file(buffer, out_file):
    for proxy in buffer:
        with open(out_file, "a+") as res:
            res.write(proxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Running...."
    in_file = "C:/Users/thomas_j_perkins/Downloads/PAC-Global-Vista.asp"
    out_file = "c:/users/thomas_j_perkins/Downloads/results.txt"
    write_to_file(extract_proxies(open(in_file, "r+")), out_file)
```

Still getting the same error:

```
Running....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pull_proxy.py", line 28, in <module>
    write_to_file(extract_proxies(open(in_file)), out_file)
  File "pull_proxy.py", line 8, in extract_proxies
    if re.compile(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$", line):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 233, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: You never actually open a file. You are just looping the string in_file.

Comment: @eandersson Ha, I just edited that into the question too

Comment: what about giving up regexes and just split it by space?

Comment: Second issue is that you are compiling the regex, not matching it, e.g. re.match.

Comment: Your Regex will only match ip addresses on their own line. Remove the carat and dollar sign to find them all. Perhaps include the quotes to reduce false matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code:

Did couple of changes

1. re.compile - Regex should be complied first and then can be used with 'match/search/findall'.
2. Regex was not proper. While writing regex we need to consider from the start of line. Regex didn't match words in between line directly.

```
 import re


    def extract_proxies(in_file):
        buffer1 = []
        #Regex compiled here
        m = re.compile(r'\s*\w+\(\w+,\s+\"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\"')

        for line in in_file:
            #Used here to match
            r = m.match(line)
            if r is not None:
                print "{} appened to buffer.".format(line)
                buffer1.append(r.group(1))
            else:
                pass

        in_file.close()
        return buffer1


    def write_to_file(buffer1, out_file):
        for proxy in buffer1:
            with open(out_file, "a+") as res:
                res.write(proxy+'\n')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "Running...."
        in_file = "sample.txt"
        out_file = "results.txt"
        write_to_file(extract_proxies(open(in_file)), out_file)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Running....
        isInNet(hostDNS, "147.163.1.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
 appened to buffer.
        isInNet(hostDNS, "123.264.0.0", "255.255.0.0") ||
 appened to buffer.
        isInNet(hostDNS, "137.5.0.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
 appened to buffer.
        isInNet(hostDNS, "100.01.02.0", "255.0.0.0") ||
 appened to buffer.
        isInNet(hostDNS, "172.146.30.0", "255.240.0.0") ||
 appened to buffer.
        isInNet(hostDNS, "112.268.0.0", "255.255.0.0") || appened to buffer.

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
```

Comment: The regex was proper, but `match` only matches the entire input string whereas search will search for a sub match.

Comment: Neither search or findall need to consider the beginning of the line.

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome  - Use this site for testing your regex - http://pythex.org/  . Its very helpful

Answer (score 2):

`re.compile` was expecting an appropriate `flags` parameter (an integer) of which `line` (a string) is not.

You should be doing `re.match` not `re.compile`:

> [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile)
>
> Compile a regular expression pattern into a regular expression object,
>   which can be used for matching using its `match()` and `search()`
>   methods...

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome Changed it to `re.match(..., line)`?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

is caused by exactly what @Moses said in his answer.  flags are supposed to be int values, not strings.

---

You should compile your regex once.  Also, you need to use an open file handle when you iterate over the lines.

import re

```
IP_MATCHER = re.compile(r"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})")

def extract_proxies(fh):
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        match = IP_MATCHER.findall(line)
        if match:
            print "{} appened to buffer.".format(line)
            print match
        else:
            pass



def write_to_file(buffer, out_file):
    for proxy in buffer:
        with open(out_file, "a+") as res:
            res.write(proxy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Running...."
    in_file = "in.txt"
    with open(in_file) as fh:
        extract_proxies(fh)
```

This will find all matches, if you only want the first, then use `IP_MATCHER.search` and `match.groups()`.  This is of course assuming you actually want to extract the IP addresses.

For instance:

```
def extract_proxies(fh):
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        match = IP_MATCHER.findall(line)
        if len(match) == 2:
            print "{} appened to buffer.".format(line)
            ip, mask = match
            print "IP: %s => Mask: %s" % (ip, mask)
        else:
            pass
```